# malloc error “memory corruption (fast) in named pipe opening

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to create some N numbers of  name pipe(fifo). I get some stratnge error after opening 14 fifo. Below is my code:-

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   if(argc != 2)                                                                                                      
   {                                                                                                                
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage:- fifo <number of fds> \n");
      exit(1);
   }

   int i = atoi(argv[1]);
   int *socket = new int(i);
   char cc[10]; 
   std::string fifo = "event.fifo";
   for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
   {
       fifo = "event.fifo";
       sprintf(cc, "%d", j);
       fifo += cc;

        unlink(fifo.c_str());
        if (mkfifo(fifo.c_str(), 0600) == -1) 
        {
                perror("mkfifo");
                exit(1);
        }

        socket[j] = open(fifo.c_str(), O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK, 0);

        if (socket[j] == -1) 
        {
                perror("open");
                exit(1);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Fifo created %s\n", fifo.c_str());
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n============================================\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My program does not crash but it gives me the error:-

```
Error in `./fifo': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x09293018
```

Answer (score 3):

Typo:

```
int *socket = new int(i);
```

should be

```
int *socket = new int[i];
```

(You were only allocating one int instead of an array.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes that was the silly mistake. Thanks a lot.